# Why is being an unregistered animagus against the law?

Tags: harry-potter, laws, morality, animagi

The wizarding world also has invisibility cloaks, disillusionment charms and polyjuice potions - using those a wizard can also disguise himself. All of those seem legal. An unregistered animagus, however, faces a sentence in Azkaban. Why is there a law against unregistered animagi at all?

Comment: Relevant: [Why isn't polyjuice potion illegal](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123965/why-isnt-polyjuice-potion-illegal)

Comment: Laws don't make no sense over theres.

Comment: It seems the punishment for breaking almost any law is Azkaban....

Comment: @Skooba yes, but why it's breaking the law if youre a cat sometimes? Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if an animal is actually an animagus? I ask because those other methods you named aren't foolproof. People under invisibility cloaks and disillusionment charms can be detected through Homenum Revelio I think. With polyjuice potion you can ask questions to see if the person is fake. But I don't know a way to detect if an animal is actually an animagus, unless you recognize the person's "distinctive markings or disabilities" being in animal form as ibid said in the answer. That may be why it was made illegal.

Comment: @Dumbeldorality there's def. one. I remember being traumatised when Sirius & Lupin used it against Scabbers and Peter appeared.

Comment: @Dumbledorality: yes, but that's a separate question. In *Chamber of Secrets*, Professor Lupin and Sirius use magic to force Peter Pettigrew to turn back to his original form, and even say something like "if it's really a rat, it won't hurt him".

Comment: @R.Skeeter I completely forgot about that! In that case I guess the ability to detect that form of concealment doesn't have an impact on why it is illegal.

Comment: @Dumbledorality well, humenum revelio is an area spell, which is much more friendly than the one to reveal animagi -  for that one you have to target every rat or ant in the house, so yours still a good point.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'd just like to say that Lupin and Sirius do that in _Prisoner of Azkaban_, not _Chamber of Secrets_

Comment: The fact that Rita Skeeter asks why being an unregistered animagus is illegal is hilarious.

Comment: Because STATISM, that's why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Animagi are most commonly used by those involved in espionage and crime

> Animagi make up a small fraction of the wizarding population. Achieving perfect, spontaneous human to animal transformation requires much study and practice, and many witches and wizards consider that their time might be better employed in other ways. Certainly, the application of such a talent is limited unless one has a great need of disguise or concealment. **It is for this reason that the Ministry of Magic has insisted upon a register of Animagi, for there can be no doubt that this kind of magic is of greatest use to those engaged in surreptitious, covert or even criminal activity.**
>   <sub>*The Tales of Beedle the Bard* - Albus Dumbledore on "Babbitty Rabbitty and her Cackling Stump"</sub>

There is nothing "illegal" about becoming an Animagus. It's just a very difficult and time consuming skill for one to learn, and the only people who can afford to spend the time are usually the people who are will be using it often. These are the types of people that the ministry would want registered.

> An Animagus has **a great potential advantage in the spheres of espionage and crime.** For this reason, an Animagus Registry exists on which all Animagi are expected to log their personal details and the precise appearance of their transformed self. It is usually the case that distinctive markings or disabilities belonging to the human body will transfer to the animal self. Failure to enter oneself onto the Registry may result in a stretch in Azkaban.
>   <sub>[Pottermore - Animagi](https://usd.shop.pottermore.com/products/short_stories_from_hogwarts_of_heroism_hardship_and_dangerous_hobbies_ebook_english) (behind paywall)</sub>

Invisibility cloaks, disillusionment charms, and polyjuice potions are all things that any witch or wizard can employ. There would be no purpose in having a registry of everyone who is Polyjuice-capable as everyone is. In contrast, only 0.1% of wizards are Animagi.

> It is immensely difficult to change oneself into an Animagus and the process, which is complex and time-consuming, can go dramatically wrong. As a result, it is believed that **fewer than one in a thousand witches or wizards are Animagi.**
>   <sub>[Pottermore - Animagi](https://usd.shop.pottermore.com/products/short_stories_from_hogwarts_of_heroism_hardship_and_dangerous_hobbies_ebook_english) (behind paywall)</sub>

Of course, an Animagus is also a much more useful form of disguise, as it doesn't require any tools, and lasts indefinitely.

One last point to be aware of is that while Animagi, Polyjuice Potion, Invisibility cloaks, and the like may be legal, breaking the law with them is not.

Comment: You mean everyone can do disguise but animagi do it with a style? As in theyre the James Bonds of the magic world?

Comment: @R.Skeeter - They can do it without access to any tools, and can do it indefinitely. Invisibility cloaks, disillusionment charms, and polyjuice potions all have highly limited lifespans.

Comment: but that's technicality. You can do crime with our without equipment. It seems it's a crime *to be* an animagi even if they do nothing wrong.

Comment: You can also underline that polyjuice potion is not infinite. And it can't change your voice.
A 80-years old with a little girl voice is strange. Not a dog who seems to be nothing more than a dog.

Comment: @Saphirel source on polyjuice not changing the voice?  I'd have thought the whole gambit in CoS would have fallen flat if the voice didn't change with the body.  Speech *patterns* are (mostly) a function of the mind, of course, but the *sound* should alter with the larynx.

Comment: @Saphirel yet the order members & ministry were paranoid about DE's polyjucing themselves checking even their closest relatives.

Comment: @ibid Off-topic: If you would consider giving a little more explanation to the point why polyjuice potion doesn't buy you a ticket to azkaban, we could close the question I linked in comments as dupe of this one.

Comment: @Darael In CoS, Harry and Ron had to speak like Crab and Goyle. Same when they used polyjuice to enter in the ministry (Ron felt really bad when he had to speak to """""his wife""""")

Comment: @Saphirel yeah, speech *patterns* and *mannerisms*, but if the *voices* didn't change only exceptional vocal mimics could have pulled it off even so.

Comment: @Darael Though movie had them sound like Harry and Ron as Crab and Goyle (which I was thoroughly confused by when I saw it, that scene played out quite differently in the movie from in the book).

Comment: @JAB there's a moderately common convention (I'd estimate about a third of cases?) of doing that in film and TV, with the audience meant to assume that they sound like who they *look* like in-universe and that the mismatched voices are to make it easier for the viewer. Either way, books trump films in my view.

Comment: Note that if the wizarding population in the UK is in the [3,000-10,000 range](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/during-the-events-of-the-harry-potter-series-what-is-the-total-population-of-wiz), and "fewer than one wizard in a thousand is an Animagus", then the five Animagi encountered over the course of the series are probably the majority—if not all—of the Animagi in the UK.  And the majority of those are unregistered.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert `it is believed that fewer than one in a thousand witches or wizards are Animagi.` — maybe it's only *believed* to be so few because this is the number of people registered :)

Comment: @anotherdave:  Fair point — after all, four out of five of the Animagi we encounter in the series are unregistered.