# Are there any known instances of animagi (registered or unregistererd) murdering other wizards?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

Following the [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144796) to the question *[Why is being an unregistered animagus against the law?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144795/why-is-being-an-unregistered-animagus-against-the-law)*, the animagi are involved in crimes and espionage.

Although it isn't exactly mentioned what crimes are committed by the animagi, has any animagi gone too far, such as killing a fellow wizard?

In other words, have there been instances where an Animagi, registered or otherwise, in their animal form, have committed murder in the Wizarding World?

Comment: 2 points: first, your title and last sentence aren't exactly the same; you should clarify which you mean.  Second, since you're talking about the motivation for laws, do you mean _publicly known in the wizarding world_ or just _known to readers_?

Comment: Aren't there only 5 Animagi known in canon? McGonagall, Wormy, Padfoot, Prongs, Skeeter.

Comment: There are crimes other than killing, and the animagus form could help get to or escape from the crime scene unrecognized, even if they don't kill in their animagus form.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

To my knowledge, there are no known instances of Animagi killing anybody in their animal form.

There have been other crimes committed by Animagi in their animal form, such as Rita Skeeter trespassing on Hogwarts Castle despite being banned from the premises, and Peter Pettigrew escaping citizen's arrest.

Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald spoilers:

> Nagini, who is not an Animagus but a Maledictus, murders Severus Snape in Deathly Hallows while she is a snake.